# Using jQuery to change the same function where the class is class_01, class_02

Tags: jquery, class, loops, increment

I have 20 classes classname_01 to classname_20
I wold rather not have to write the same code 20 times because of the _00 in the class name. The sample of my code is:

```
$('.tab_01').on('click',function(e) {
    $('#interactive_folder span').removeClass().addClass('folder_01');
    $(hideus).hide();
    $('img.folder_info_01 , .cte_01').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('.tab_02').on('click',function(e) {
    $('#interactive_folder span').removeClass().addClass('folder_02');
    $(hideus).hide();
    $('img.folder_info_02 , .sub_title_02 , .cte_02').show()
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Could someone advise a way to increment the number on the class names.

Edit Adding HTML

```
<div id="legend">
        <table id="layout_table" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><p data-id="01" class="legend_icon icon_01 tab">Legend 01</p></td>
            <td><p data-id="02" class="legend_icon icon_02 tab">Legend 02</p></td>
            <td><p data-id="03" class="legend_icon icon_03 tab">Legend 03</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p data-id="04" class="legend_icon icon_04 tab">Legend 04</p></td>
            <td><p data-id="05" class="legend_icon icon_05 tab">Legend 05</p></td>
            <td><p data-id="06" class="legend_icon icon_06 tab">Legend 06</p></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
      <div id="interactive_folder">
      <p class="folder_title">REPORT</p>
        <span class="folder_01"></span>
        <img src="../../img/folder_info_01.png" alt="" class="folder_info_01" width="457" height="524" />
        <div class="cte_01"><a class="popup_extlarge" href="" target="_blank"><img src="../../img/enlarge-01.png" width="175" height="108"></a></div>
        <p class="sub_title_02">Title 01</p>
        <div class="cte_02"><a class="popup_extlarge" href="" target="_blank"><img src="../../img/enlarge-02.png" width="175" height="108"></a></div>
        <img src="../../img/folder_info_02.png" class="folder_info_02" width="451" height="213" />
        <p class="sub_title_03">Title 02</p>
        <div class="cte_03"><a class="popup_extlarge" href="../../img/expense-budget-cost-centres.png" target="_blank"><img src="../../img/enlarge-03.png" width="175" height="108"></a></div>
        <img src="../../img/folder_info_03.png" class="folder_info_03" width="467" height="366" />
        <p class="sub_title_04">Title 03</p>
        <div class="cte_04"><a class="popup_extlarge" href="../../img/expense-budget-cost-centres.png" target="_blank"><img src="../../img/enlarge-04.png" width="175" height="108"></a></div>
        <img src="../../img/folder_info_04.png" class="folder_info_04" width="467" height="156" />
        <p class="sub_title_05">Title 04</p>
        <div class="cte_05"><a class="popup_extlarge" href="../../img/expense-budget-cost-centres.png" target="_blank"><img src="../../img/enlarge-05.png" width="175" height="108"></a></div>
        <img src="../../img/folder_info_05.png" class="folder_info_05" width="466" height="140" />
        <p class="sub_title_06">Title 05</p>
        <div class="cte_06"><a class="popup_extlarge" href="../../img/expense-budget-cost-centres.png" target="_blank"><img src="../../img/enlarge-06.png" width="175" height="108"></a></div>
        <img src="../../img/folder_info_06.png" class="folder_info_06" width="466" height="135" />
      </div>
```

New code is

```
var hideus = $('.folder_info_01, .folder_info_02, .folder_info_03, .folder_info_04, .folder_info_05, .folder_info_06, .sub_title_02, .sub_title_03, .sub_title_04, .sub_title_05, .sub_title_06, .cte_01, .cte_02, .cte_03, .cte_04, .cte_05, .cte_06');

$(hideus).hide();
$('.folder_info_01 , .cte_01').show();


$('.tab').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
        suffix = $this.data("id");

    $('#interactive_folder span').removeClass().addClass('folder_' + suffix );
    $(hideus).hide();
    $('img.folder_info_' + suffix + ' , .cte_' + suffix).show();
});
```

Comment: Can I see some of the HTML you have to go with it? If the tabs all belong to the same parent element and have no sibling other than other tabs, then you could use a jQuery selector (parent > ele) to select the type of element it is, then grab part of the class name to find the number, and finish the rest with that number. edit: semantics

Comment: Ahh well the aria roles are a mute point now as I just found out that Aria 1.1 will be dropping the drag and drop roles anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tip: use the `data-*` attribute along with a common class.

HTML Example:

```
<div class="my-tab" data-id="01">...</div>
<div class="my-tab" data-id="02">...</div>
<div class="my-tab" data-id="03">...</div>
```

JavaScript Example:

```
$('.my-tab').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
        suffix = $this.data("id");

    $('#interactive_folder span').removeClass().addClass('folder_' + suffix );
    $(hideus).hide(); // note: hideus is note defined in scope here
    $('img.folder_info_' + suffix + ' , .cte_' + suffix).show();
});
```

**Note:** Logic aside, and without seeing your markup, it would be hard to recommend going down this path. There's a bit of tedious manipulation which you may be able to do with a simple targeting of a parent container.

Comment: $(hideus).hide(); // note: hideus is note defined in scope here

var hideus = $('.folder_info_01, .folder_info_02, .folder_info_03, .folder_info_04, .folder_info_05, .folder_info_06, .sub_title_02, .sub_title_03, .sub_title_04, .sub_title_05, .sub_title_06, .cte_01, .cte_02, .cte_03, .cte_04, .cte_05, .cte_06');

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a loop to iterate over the different classes, adding their event handlers, and passing a parameter with the current, associated index:

```
// Traverse the 20 tabs
var i;
for(i=1;i<=20;i++) {
  // Add a preceding zero character for IDs under 10
  var precedingZero = (i<10) ? '0' : '';
  var currentTabClass = ".tab_" + precedingZero + i;
  // Add an event handler for each tab, passing the current counter value, i, as a param in the event
  $(currentTabClass).on('click',{currentIndex:i+''},function(e) {
    // Retrieve the current index
    var theIndex = e.data.currentIndex;
    $('#interactive_folder span').removeClass().addClass('folder_' + theIndex);
    $(hideus).hide();
    $('img.folder_info_' + theIndex + ' , .cte_' + theIndex).show();
    e.preventDefault();
  });  
}
```

See it working [in this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNvqWE?editors=101).

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not want to change source code you can use:

```js
$('[class^=tab_]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('img[class^=folder_info_], [class^=cte_]').hide();
    var thisNumber=$(this).attr('class').replace('tab_', '');
    $('#interactive_folder span').removeClass().addClass('folder_' + thisNumber);
    $('img.folder_info_' + thisNumber + ', .cte_' + thisNumber).show();
});
```

```css
.folder_01 {
    color: red;
}
.folder_02 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="tab_01">TAB 01 (click me)</li>
    <li class="tab_02">TAB 02 (click me)</li>
</ul>

<div id="interactive_folder"><span>Span</span></div>

<img class="folder_info_01" style="display: none;" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
<div class="cte_01" style="display: none;">CTE 01</div>

<img class="folder_info_02" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" style="display: none;" />
<div class="cte_02" style="display: none;">CTE 02</div>
```

Note: My guess those are only classes for elements you target. If you have more than class, than the script would be little bit complicated.

Note 2: I am 100% sure this is not a correct way of coding. If you post your html code, than you will get much better answer.

Comment: Thanks this works but I went with technophobia's solution.